# SMTP relay office365 with pmta

Tags: office365, microsoft-exchange, pmta

i do have a prolbem using pmta smtp relay so whenever i do an smtp relay in pmta i goet this problem

SMTP service unavailable: STARTTLS required but failed: SSL error: 140596247639808:error:1411809D:SSL routines:SSL_CHECK_SERVERHELLO_TLSEXT:tls invalid ecpointformat list:t1_lib.c:1469:;140596247639808:error:14092113:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_HELLO:serverhello tlsext:s3_clnt.c:942:; at smtp.office365.com (40.101.72.114:587) while connected from steezyviralxxxx.com (80.211.xxx.xx) to smtp.office365.com (40.101.72.114:587)

where 80.. is my Ip adress and domain Steezy...

and this is the config that i use to do the relay thing on pmta

```
<domain *>
auth-username bingo@pifo.onmicrosoft.com
auth-password xxxx
require-starttls yes
use-starttls yes
route smtp.office365.com:587
</domain>
```

i tried the connectos tricks but none worked... the problem is for both inbound and outbound email services thank you very much !

Comment: I'm not sure if you realize that this isn't a programming question by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: i can clearly see this but where else is there the Pro IT guys ? ! and since there is some question related to pmta i said why not asking pros here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u missed "use-unencrypted-plain-auth yes"
try this and it will work :)

```
<domain *>
auth-username bingo@pifo.onmicrosoft.com
auth-password xxxx
use-unencrypted-plain-auth yes
require-starttls yes
use-starttls yes
route smtp.office365.com:587
</domain>
```

Comment: after you test get back to me with confirmation if it works

Comment: Hello Mate i tested this Lately but nothing Worked... ty for helping